# Read JSON file & parse to get element values in shell script

Tags: json, shell

I have a json file names test.json with the below content.

```
{
        "run_list": ["recipe[cookbook-ics-op::setup_server]"],
    "props": {
        "install_home": "/test/inst1",
            "tmp_dir": "/test/inst1/tmp",
        "user": "tuser
                 }
}
```

I want to read this file into a variable in shell script & then extract the values of install_home,user & tmp_dir using expr. Can someone help, please?

props=`cat test.json`

works to get the json file into a variable. Now how can I extract the values using expr. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `expr` or regular expressions (anticipating some nasty regex-based answers). Use a proper JSON parser such as `jq`.

Comment: The sample JSON supplied is malformed, it's missing a closing double quote on the line that says `tuser`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Answer (score 5):

Install jq

```
yum -y install epel-release
yum -y install jq
```

Get the values in the following way

```
install_home=$(cat test.json  | jq -r '.props.install_home')
tmp_dir=$(cat test.json  | jq -r '.props.tmp_dir')
user=$(cat test.json  | jq -r '.props.user')
```

Answer (score 4):

jq is a dedicated parser for JSON files. Install jq.

values in the json can be retrieved as:

`jq .<top-level-attr>.<next-level-attr> <json-file-path>`

if JSON contains an array

`jq .<top-level-attr>.<next-level-array>[].<elem-in-array> <json-file-path>`

if you want a value in a shell variable

`id = $(jq -r .<top-level-attr>.<next-level-array>[].<next-level-attr> <json-file-path>)`

`echo id`

use -r if you need unquoted value

Answer (score 3):

For a pure bash solution I suggest this:
[github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh)
It could be used like this:

```
./json.sh -l -p < example.json
```

print output like:

```
["name"]        "JSON.sh"
["version"]     "0.2.1"
["description"] "JSON parser written in bash"
["homepage"]    "http://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh"
["repository","type"]   "git"
["repository","url"]    "https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh.git"
["bin","JSON.sh"]       "./JSON.sh"
["author"]      "Dominic Tarr <dominic.tarr@gmail.com> (http://bit.ly/dominictarr)"
["scripts","test"]      "./all-tests.sh"
```

From here is pretty trivial achive what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

For simple JSON, it may be treated as a plain text file.
In that case, we can use simple text pattern matching to extract the information we need.

If you observe the following lines:

```
    "install_home": "/test/inst1",
        "tmp_dir": "/test/inst1/tmp",
    "user": "user"
```

There exists a pattern on each line that can be described as `key` and `value`:

- `"key"` `:` `"value"`

We can use `perl` with regular expressions to exact the `value` for any given key:

- `"key"` hardcoded for each case `"install_home"`, `"tmp_dir"` and `"user"`
- `"value"` as `(.*)` regular expression

Then we use the `$1` matching group to retrieve the value.

```sh
i=$(perl -ne 'if (/"install_home": "(.*)"/) { print $1 . "\n" }' test.json)
t=$(perl -ne 'if (/"tmp_dir": "(.*)"/) { print $1 . "\n" }' test.json)
u=$(perl -ne 'if (/"user": "(.*)"/) { print $1 . "\n" }' test.json)

cat <<EOF
install_home: $i
tmp_dir     : $t
user        : $u
EOF
```

Which outputs:

```
install_home: /test/inst1
tmp_dir     : /test/inst1/tmp
user        : tuser
```

Comment: While this might work for a simple json, for more complex json using regex will be a nightmare!